# Diagnosing "% Time in Garbage Collection" Problems

Tags: asp.net, debugging, garbage-collection

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 application that spends an excessive amount of time in garbage collection, over 40%, when load tested on a production grade server (dual quad-core, 4g). 
I have been trying to isolate the problem but it is a large, complex code base making for slow going.  There are no GC.Collect() calls.  Which tools, techniques, etc. are helpful when trying to isolate this type of problem?

Answer (score 3):

Start off by profiling your app using the [.Net CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=A362781C-3870-43BE-8926-862B40AA0CD0&displaylang=en) (it's got a spiffy GUI for displaying collected data and it's FREE!). Specific instructions for how to profile ASP.Net app can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms979205.aspx#scalenethowto13_topic5) and [this article](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/CLR-Profiler) is a good overview of the GC with respect to memory/performance problems, profiling, and the .Net CLR Profiler.

Answer (score 2):

Try seeing if someone on your team has actually overridden `Dispose()` methods to frequently call `GC.Collect()`. This happened on my team and it got so bad that one of the `Dispose()` methods took 1 whole second to execute.

This is the only way I could imagine your server spending 40% of its time in garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, my trick knee is acting up, and when it does that, it either means it's about to snow, or someone has been using a lot of "+" operators for string concatenation instead of using StringBuilder as the good lord intended.

What about [ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/ants_profiler/index.htm)?  I'd used that a while back and liked it.  There's also a [Profiling API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300553.aspx) you can use to catch your own data.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the GC to use up 100% CPU time, shortly before the entire app crashed. The problem was an 'object leak' where we leaked 20mb at a time. Eventually the GC gave up trying and memory was exhausted.

You can see how long its doing this using perfmon, there is a GC object with quite a few counters.